# icomoon @font-face not being included in minified CSS

Tags: css, fonts, gulp

I am using a Gulp plugin (gulp-minify-css) to concat then minify my CSS, and for some reason it strips out the entire `@font-face` rule from the minified CSS. I am also using fonts from Google Fonts, and it doesn't strip this.

The font face rules

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?91yt6w');
  src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix91yt6w') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.woff?91yt6w') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf?91yt6w') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.svg?91yt6w#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

By all outward appearance, this code is fine. It comes from IcoMoon themselves. I have tried stripping the string after `?` in the file url, but that wasn't it.

Anybody have any insight, as we have only just discovered this whilst trying to deploy.

Comment: Does gulp error when it tries to build? Do you mean you already concatenated the css, so you have a .css file that has this chunk of code in it and when you try to minify this 1 file it removes it? Or is it a whole process where it concats and minifies in 1 task?

Comment: No errors and builds fine, everything else is as it should be. I'm concatenating CSS, then minifying. If I don't minify, everything works as I should. The whole process is concat then minify.

Comment: I tried to minify that css in a few online tools and it worked fine. I kind of feel like the problem might be somewhere else, but its hard to say without seeing the whole process. I also haven't had an issue minifying font-face with gulp.

Comment: I found it, thank you for your time. It was a gulp-combine-media-queries plugin. It was stripping it for some reason.